# how to make child controllers within ng-repeat load one at a time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a main controller which gets data representing x and y coordinates of a table(rows and columns).

Within each cell I have a child controller which prepares the values it will render on basis of x & y values of parent controller.

At the moment nothing is rendered on the screen until the whole thing is processed.

The behaviour I am after is that first the whole table is rendered showing only column header values and first cell values within each row. And than have the child controller load the cell values one at a time...

Simplified demo of non wanted behaviour:
https://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/xmtg3q31/1/

template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Y/X</th>
      <th ng-repeat="valX in x">{{valX}}</th>
    <tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="valY in y">
      <td>{{valY}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="valX in x">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
          {{value}}
        </div>
      </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
    $scope.y =      ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
}

function MyCtrl2($scope) {
    $scope.value = $scope.valX + $scope.valY;
}
```

The real thing:

template:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="comparison">
    <div ng-controller="comparisonController" class="container-fluid">
      <h3>Choose comparison table structure</h3>
      <div class="multiDropMenus" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="colXoptions" selected-model="colXoptionsModel" translation-texts="xBtnLabel" extra-settings="settingsXaxisBtn" events="updateModelX">
      </div>
      <div class="multiDropMenus" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="colYoptions" selected-model="colYoptionsModel" translation-texts="yBtnLabel" extra-settings="settingsYaxisBtn" events="updateModelY">
      </div>
      <div class="multiDropMenus" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="colValueoptions" selected-model="colValueoptionsModel" translation-texts="valueBtnLabel" extra-settings="settingsValueaxisBtn" events="updateModelV">
      </div>
      <div class="multiDropMenus" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="colGroupingoptions" selected-model="colGroupingoptionsModel" translation-texts="groupingBtnLabel" extra-settings="settingsGroupingaxisBtn" events="updateModelG">
      </div>
      <br>
      <button ng-if="colXoptionsModel && colYoptionsModel && colValueoptionsModel && colGroupingoptionsModel" ng-click="createTable()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-xs-12"><span class=""></span> Create table</button>
      <br>
      <div class="container-fluid" style="overflow-x:scroll;">
        <table ng-if="tableReady" class="table-bordered" style="width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;">
          <tr>
            <th>{{colYoptionsModel.attobj.name}}/{{colXoptionsModel.attobj.name}}</th>
            <th ng-repeat="x in uniqueX" ng-init="colHeader = x.get4(colXoptionsModel.key)[0].attributes.displayName[0] || x.get4(colXoptionsModel.key).toString()">
              {{colHeader}}
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="y in uniqueY" ng-init="rowIndex = y.get4(colYoptionsModel.key)[0].attributes.displayName[0] || y.get4(colYoptionsModel.key).toString()">
            <td>{{rowIndex}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="x in uniqueX">
              <div ng-controller="comparisonValues">
                  <div ng-repeat="dbo in cellValues">
                    <div ng-if="grouping" ng-init="attobj = colGroupingoptionsModel; key = attobj.key; values=dbo.get4(attobj.key); template = attobj.template || getAttributeTemplate(dbo.clazz + attobj.key);">
                      <div class="contentDecompressed" customtemp></div>
                    </div>
                    <span style="clear:both;"></span>
                    <div ng-init="attobj = colValueoptionsModel; key = attobj.key; values=dbo.get4(attobj.key); template = attobj.template || getAttributeTemplate(dbo.clazz + attobj.key);">
                      <div class="contentDecompressed" customtemp></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('comparisonValues', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {
        console.log('loading cell');
        //filter allDBOS where xmodel col = x and ymodel col = y
        var checkX = $scope.x.get4($scope.colXoptionsModel.key)[0].cid || $scope.x.get4($scope.colXoptionsModel.key).toString();
        var checkY = $scope.y.get4($scope.colYoptionsModel.key)[0].cid || $scope.y.get4($scope.colYoptionsModel.key).toString();

        $scope.cellValues = _.filter($scope.allDBOS, function(dbo){ 
          var checkDboX = dbo.get4($scope.colXoptionsModel.key)[0].cid || dbo.get4($scope.colXoptionsModel.key).toString();
          var checkDboY = dbo.get4($scope.colYoptionsModel.key)[0].cid || dbo.get4($scope.colYoptionsModel.key).toString(); 

          if(checkDboX == checkX && checkDboY == checkY){
            return dbo;
          }
        });
        if($scope.cellValues.length > 1){
          $scope.grouping = true;
        }
        $scope.compressed=false;

}]);

app.controller('comparisonController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$q', 'templateService',
  function ($scope, $location, $http, $q, templateService) {
    $scope.getAttributeTemplate = templateService.getAttributeTemplate;

    $scope.tableReady = false;
    $scope.compare.val = false;

    $scope.colXoptions = $scope.columns;
    $scope.colXoptionsModel={}
    $scope.settingsXaxisBtn = {closeOnSelect:true, displayProp: 'key', idProp: 'key', externalIdProp:'', selectionLimit: 1, buttonClasses:'graphDropDowns', smartButtonMaxItems: 1, showUncheckAll:false, showCheckAll:false};
    $scope.xBtnLabel = {buttonDefaultText:'X-Axis'};
    $scope.updateModleX = {
      onItemSelect: function(item) { 
        $scope.updateModleX = $scope.updateModleX;
      },
      onItemDeselect: function(item) { 
       $scope.updateModleX = {};

      }
    };

    $scope.colYoptions = $scope.columns;
    $scope.colYoptionsModel={}
    $scope.settingsYaxisBtn = {closeOnSelect:true, displayProp: 'key', idProp: 'key', externalIdProp:'', selectionLimit: 1, buttonClasses:'graphDropDowns', smartButtonMaxItems: 1, showUncheckAll:false, showCheckAll:false};
    $scope.yBtnLabel = {buttonDefaultText:'Y-Axis'};
    $scope.updateModleY = {
      onItemSelect: function(item) { 
        $scope.colYoptionsModel = $scope.colYoptionsModel;
      },
      onItemDeselect: function(item) { 
       $scope.colYoptionsModel = {};

      }
    };

    $scope.colValueoptions = $scope.columns;
    $scope.colValueoptionsModel={}
    $scope.settingsValueaxisBtn = {closeOnSelect:true, displayProp: 'key', idProp: 'key', externalIdProp:'', selectionLimit: 1, buttonClasses:'graphDropDowns', smartButtonMaxItems: 1, showUncheckAll:false, showCheckAll:false};
    $scope.valueBtnLabel = {buttonDefaultText:'Value-Axis'};
    $scope.updateModleV = {
      onItemSelect: function(item) { 
        $scope.colValueoptionsModel = $scope.colValueoptionsModel;
      },
      onItemDeselect: function(item) { 
       $scope.colValueoptionsModel = {};

      }
    };

    $scope.colGroupingoptions = $scope.columns;
    $scope.colGroupingoptionsModel={}
    $scope.settingsGroupingaxisBtn = {closeOnSelect:true, displayProp: 'key', idProp: 'key', externalIdProp:'', selectionLimit: 1, buttonClasses:'graphDropDowns', smartButtonMaxItems: 1, showUncheckAll:false, showCheckAll:false};
    $scope.groupingBtnLabel = {buttonDefaultText:'Grouping-Axis'};
    $scope.updateModleG = {
      onItemSelect: function(item) { 
        $scope.colGroupingoptionsModel = $scope.colGroupingoptionsModel;
      },
      onItemDeselect: function(item) { 
       $scope.colGroupingoptionsModel = {};

      }
    };

    //get all dbos from query without pagination
    $scope.createTable = function(){
      $scope.tableReady=false;
      $scope.query2 = angular.copy($scope.queryObj);
      var url = '/api/list2/json/' + $scope.class;
      $scope.query2.count = 0;
      $scope.query2.page = 1;

      var len = url.length + JSON.stringify($scope.query2).length + $location.url().length;
      var prom = (len > 2000)
        ? $http.post(url, {'q':JSON.stringify($scope.query2), 'hashfragment' : $location.url()}, {transformResponse: transformResponse})
        : $http.get(url, {cache:true, params:{"q":JSON.stringify($scope.query2)}, headers:{'hashfragment':$location.url()}, transformResponse: transformResponse});
      prom.then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.allDBOS = response.data.data.requested;
            console.log('alldbos');
            console.log($scope.allDBOS.length);
            $scope.getUniqueXY();
        },
        function (response) {
          // console.log('response failed to load');
      });

      return prom;     
    }

    //get distinct values for allDBOS.x and allDBOS.y model to use as table col headers(x) and table row indexes(y)
    $scope.getUniqueXY = function(){
      $scope.uniqueX = _.uniq($scope.allDBOS, function(dbo) { 
        return dbo.get4($scope.colXoptionsModel.key)[0].cid || dbo.get4($scope.colXoptionsModel.key).toString();   
      });     

      $scope.uniqueY = _.uniq($scope.allDBOS, function(dbo) { 
        return dbo.get4($scope.colYoptionsModel.key)[0].cid || dbo.get4($scope.colYoptionsModel.key).toString();   
      });
      // console.log('unique x vals in dbos');
      // console.log($scope.uniqueX.length);
      // console.log('unique y vals in dbos');
      // console.log($scope.uniqueY.length);

      //table starts to render nad directive for each cell kicks in: app.directive('loadComparisonValues'...
      $scope.tableReady = true; 
      console.log($scope.tableReady);
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Could  you highlight the **relevant part** of your code instead of pasting your whole app?

Comment: That would be the simplified version in the jsfiddle, first template and controller blocks of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do this with [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

First, keep track of current row in the view by adding a count

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Y/X</th>
      <th ng-repeat="valX in x">{{valX}}</th>
    <tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="valY in y" ng-init="count = $index;">
      <td>{{valY}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="valX in x">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
          {{value}}
        </div>
      </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And use the count in the MyCtrl2 controller to make the rows render after each other by multiplying the time with the counter

```
function MyCtrl2($scope, $timeout) {
        $timeout(function(){
         $scope.value = $scope.valX + $scope.valY;
    }, 100 * $scope.count);
}
```

Here's the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/m8geectd/1/)